# VS Code autocomplete for object properties

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have the following `env.js` JS file:

```
const env = {
    ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    DEBUG:
        (process.env.REACT_APP_DEBUG == 1 ||
        process.env.REACT_APP_DEBUG === "true"),
    PUBLIC_URL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL
};

export default env;
```

When I import it in another file and try to reference one of `env`'s object properties:

```
import env from "./env";

const DEBUG = env.<I start typing and I do not see any autocomplete for ENV, DEBUG or PUBLIC_URL>
```

VS Code does not autocomplete the properties of the `env` object.
Why doesn't it do it and how can I fix it in order to have the autocomplete functioning in this case?

Here's the content of my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // No module system, concatenated file
        "module": "none",

        // Set React as the JSX factory
        "jsx": "react",

        // Resolve modules using Node-resolution algorithm
        "moduleResolution": "node",

        // Target ES6 for more modern browsers
        "target": "es6",

        // Include typings from built-in lib declarations
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom", "dom.iterable"],

        // Include module source maps for debugging
        "sourceMap": true,

        // Output to single concatenated file
        "outFile": "dist/bundle.js",

        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I also noticed that if I change `env.js` to:

```
export default {
    ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    DEBUG:
        (process.env.REACT_APP_DEBUG == 1 ||
        process.env.REACT_APP_DEBUG === "true"),
    PUBLIC_URL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL
}
```

Then the autocomplete works:

```
import env from "./env";

const DEBUG = env.<I start typing and I see the autocomplete for ENV, DEBUG or PUBLIC_URL>
```

Why does it work in this second case and not in the first case?